# Dynamic dependency injection of a generic class

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm pretty new to the .Net world and I faced a problem that I couldn't find a solution to and I would like you to help me with it please.

I have a generic class that implements a generic interface and when I was implementing the dependency injection I didn't know how I can make it dynamic.

For example:

```
services.AddSingleton<IGenericRepository<Game>, GenericRepository<Game>>();
```

I have multiple classes that i want to pass to the generic class/interface (**Game** is one of them) and I know that I have to repeat this line for every single one of them but i was wondering of there is any way to make this dynamic.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is called an "open generic" registration. You didn't say exactly what DI framework you're using, but for most DI frameworks, the syntax is something like:

```cs
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
```

My guess is that you're using Microsoft DI framework. If so, the relevant documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.0). Search for the word "generic".

Comment: Wow, I somehow totally spaced on this one. Fail. This is definitely what OP is looking for, as opposed to my seriously overengineered answer... :)

Comment: Thank you, this's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use reflection to load all your model types, if they're all in the same namespace. Something like:

```c#
// You can use Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() if the models are in the same assembly this code runs from
var assembly = typeof(SomeTypeInAssembly).Assembly;

var modelTypes = assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.IsClass && t.Namespace == "Namespace.For.Your.Models");

foreach (var modelType in modelTypes)
{
    services.AddScoped<IGenericRepository<modelType>, GenericRepository<modelType>>();
}
```

Where `SomeTypeInAssembly` is a type in the same assembly where your models live, and `"Namespace.For.Your.Models"` is the full namespace your models are in.